# Using ghostscript to create a pdf from a ps file

Tags: vb.net, cmd, ghostscript

I am currently trying to convert some .ps files programmatically to pdf - but I am running into gswin64c, which has no usable tutorial whatsoever :(

Basically, I come up with this so far:

```
Dim proc As New Process

proc.StartInfo.FileName = My.Settings.GhostscriptPath 'path to the ghostscript bin directory
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("c:\test dire\test.ps")

'output umschreiben
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

Dim PDfName = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension("c:\test dire\test.ps", "pdf")
Dim Args As String = String.Format("-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile='{0}' '{1}'", PDfName, FileName)
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Args
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
Dim Output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
Dim OutputErrors = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd
Debug.Print(Output)
Debug.Print(OutputErrors)
```

It runs - but ghotscript simply spews a "no such file or directory" error and exits. What needs to be done to actually RUN this thing?

Comment: You are just executing under CLI, so it's not like you are accessing GS API or so. Type `gswin64c --help` on command prompt and you'll get a brief description and pointer to `Use.htm` file, which you should explore a bit before trying to do anything with GS. You could also test your command on command prompt before trying to execute from script.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument string uses single quotes around the file name placeholders:

```
"-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile='{0}' '{1}'"
```

Single quotes, however, are not valid quoting characters in `CMD`, so the command most likely fails because it's looking for a literal file name `'c:\test dire\test.ps'` instead of `c:\test dire\test.ps`. Use double quotes instead:

```
"-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=""{0}"" ""{1}"""
```

They have to be escaped by prepending them with another double quote.